# Is "When since" correct?

Tags: questions, rhetorical-devices

A friend of mine recently used an expression "When since" to start a question that could just as well start with "since when". I feel like it's incorrect, but a google search doesn't bring up any reference to "when since" used in that context. Shouldn't the question word be first?

My bad if I'm ignorant. (and my apologies for the plebeian English skills displayed here).

Comment: No, _when since_ is not idiomatic English.

Comment: The 'question word' does not always come first - from where have you come?

Comment: Context needed!!!

Comment: @HotLicks I'd rather not give the full sentence that he wrote as controversial and related to current events. Just imagine anything that you'd use "Since when" for.

Comment: When, since the origin of languages, has context been irrelevant?

Comment: Why do you believe that a single instance might be idiomatic? Is your friend a native English speaker? Have they been speaking English for only a year? Are you planning to correct them if it turns out they made a mistake? There are too many variables to be able to answer your question, and it's too specific to be of use to others.

Answer (score 1):

It's unusual. *Since when* is more common. But whether it's right depends on the sentence.

For example, there's nothing wrong with: "When, since I last saw you, did you decide to grow that silly mustache?"

(Except that it's rude.)

Comment: But OP's question doesn't have the comma after when.

Comment: @RamPillai Yeah my friend didn't use a comma. I can see how it would work with a comma.